# Running a Java process in Windows even after the user is logged out

Tags: java, windows, windows-services

I have a batch file that starts a Java process in a Windows 2003 server. As per the security policy, the users of that machine are logged off forcefully, if the user is inactive for a certain period of time. The problem is that when the user is logged out, the process also dies.

I scheduled a new task (Control Panel -> Scheduled Tasks) and selected the option of 'When my computer starts' and gave the user account details there. But it doesn't seem to have any effect, the user is still logged out and the process dies. Is a reboot necessary to make this change effective? And after the reboot, will I achieve what I'm expecting (keeping the process alive)?

Alternatively, will running this process as a Windows Service solve the problem? If so, can you please let me know how I can make a Java program or a batch file to run as a Windows Service? I would prefer not to use any other third party tools or libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping the process with srvany.exe and launching as a service would work as well.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

Comment: I use `NSSM` for the same purpose, but when it starts under SYSTEM user I'm not able to attach any memory profiler to it because it's no more visible to logged in user. `jps` and `jcmd` commands are not displaying these processes, either.

Answer (score 11):

If you want it to run under Scheduled tasks you have to make sure you don't have "only run when user logged in" checked, which usually means you need to supply a password.

A windows service would be the normal way to do this: the [Java service wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/introduction.html) is 3rd party but loads of people use it.

If you really wanted to not use a 3rd party method you could use [svrany.exe (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) on WIndows NT or later, but it is not designed specifically for Java.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I don't have that particular option set and I have supplied the password details.
I learnt about the Java Service Wrapper in another thread. I'm planning to use it as a last resort.

Comment: I love the Java service wrapper. Have been using it for a couple years and it works well.

Comment: The problem with scheduled task is by default it will run the process with 'below normal' priority. This might cause performance issue when the server is under some load

Answer (score 2):

I don't know it this is relevant but we are using a flag to the jvm so it does not shutdown on logoffs

```
"java -Xrs"
```

[Link to suns description of -Xrs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#nonstandard)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org) to start the java process as windows service.
I guess it works similary to the srvany.exe mentioned in the previous posting.

Answer (score 0):

As per my analysis,

The Idle Solution will be writing a VC++ (.net) Windows Service creation program  to launch the .bat / .exe as a System service with all the required call back methods to SCM.

**Note** : 
1. Wrapping the process with srvany.exe would not work as it does not have any call back process to the SCM (Service Control Manager). 
2. And java service Wrapper is a third party API (many are LGPL licensed).