# how to run webapps on tomcat automatically

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

i have deployed a java server using my eclipse.

I extract the `war` file.

i installed the `apache-tomcat-7.0.47` on my windows server 2003

i installed the `Apache Tomcat 7` service on my windows server 2003 and made it run automatically.

i want to run the `war` file on my windows server 2003

#### what i have tried

i put the `war` file on my webapps on the `apache-tomcat` folder and then run the `startup.bat` which locates on the `bin` folder.

i test the server and it works perfectly

#### my problem

when i log of from my windows server. the war file stop working.

#### my question

how can i keep the server working ever when i log of. **note that i installed the service and restart the server many times.**

Comment: when you log off from the windows server at that time is the tomcat running or its stopped?

Comment: @JqueryLearner running ofc. i am really confusied. i have done that on many servers before. i dont know what am i doing wrong this time

Comment: when you logout can you telnet to the tomcat server port?

Comment: @PaulWhelan sorry i don't understand your question. can u descripe more please?

Comment: Are you logging off from administrator?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli just wanted to know if your tomcat is running or not when you log off your system.As paul has said try to do telnet.syntax telnet ipaddress port number. example telnet 192.168.0.32 8080

Comment: @aksappy yes i am the admistrator

Comment: @JqueryLearner when i logoff and i tried to call the localhost of my tomcat using this `ip:port` from another computer on the networks, i got the home page of apache. that means the apache server is running

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli If the tomcat server is running then its obvious that your app is also running.How do you run your app after log off?

Comment: @JqueryLearner **before** logof, i run the server in this way `ip:port/homepage` . **after** logof, i run the server in the exact same way. notice as i told you the localhost of the server is working although after logof

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli This is just a strange issue,well I will try to help you.Do you have teamviewer installed?

Comment: @JqueryLearner finally i found the answer, thanks to `aksappy` help, check my answer please :)

Comment: @JqueryLearner i appreciate your support and your pation on me and my bad english, i thank you very much.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli always ready to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading `aksappy`'s answer. I discovered that the jvm is making that problem. i went to the `bin` folder of the `apache-tomcat` and run the `tomcat7w.exe` and then I went to the shutdown tab and changed the `jvm` to `java`.

#### this is the facinate solution that helped me

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to use a [Java Server Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/introduction.html) or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

[SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553175/running-a-java-process-in-windows-even-after-the-user-is-logged-out)

There seems to be a way in java itself to do this, add -Xrs to your java.exe call in server startup (bat file I suppose), from [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) . Beware of the consequences in using this!

> -Xrs Reduces use of operating-system signals by the Java VM.
>
> In an earlier release, the Shutdown Hooks facility was added to enable
>   orderly shutdown of a Java application. The intent was to enable user
>   cleanup code (such as closing database connections) to run at
>   shutdown, even if the Java VM terminates abruptly.
>
> The Java VM watches for console control events to implement shutdown
>   hooks for unexpected Java VM termination. Specifically, the Java VM
>   registers a console control handler which begins shutdown-hook
>   processing and returns TRUE for CTRL_C_EVENT, CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT,
>   CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT, and CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT.
>
> The JVM uses a similar mechanism to implement the feature of dumping
>   thread stacks for debugging purposes. The JVM uses CTRL_BREAK_EVENT to
>   perform thread dumps.
>
> If the Java VM is run as a service (for example, the servlet engine
>   for a web server), then it can receive CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT but should
>   not initiate shutdown because the operating system will not actually
>   terminate the process. To avoid possible interference such as this,
>   the -Xrs command-line option was added beginning with J2SE 1.3.1. When
>   the -Xrs option is used on the Java VM, the Java VM does not install a
>   console control handler, implying that it does not watch for or
>   process CTRL_C_EVENT, CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT, or
>   CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT.
>
> There are two consequences of specifying -Xrs:
>
> Ctrl-Break thread dumps are not available.
>
> User code is responsible for causing shutdown hooks to run, for
>   example by calling System.exit() when the Java VM is to be terminated.

Comment: you are the brillitn one. thank you very much. you inspire me to the soulution , please read my answer, and i really really really apprecaite you help, you are great

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Anytime mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **“deployIgnore”** attribute for your web application in server.xml ; this attribute will ignore the war file name from deployment. Later you can deployment the application manually

Comment: i dont want deploying manually, i already can. i want to keep the server running even when i log of. you know it is a server and this is its job :)